The picture on my Nikon D5300 is dark, both in live view and through the viewfinder
I turned my Nikon D5300 on today after a few months of non use, and I found that the image is dark, both in live view and through the viewfinder. Like, if I look at my Christmas tree, I see the lights, but nothing else. If I point it to the window, I see the street, but nothing from the room I am in. This happens with both lenses, which, by the way, I know to be damaged; one has the AF broken, and the other one has a stuck zoom ring. But beside this, last time I tried I was able to take good pictures, both in auto and manual.
I read around and it seems like this can happen when the battery is not inserted, because in modern DSLR energy from the battery is used to lighten up a normally dark LCD screen. But the battery is inserted and the camera seems to be operational. It even says "Subject too dark" when I try to shoot.
There could also be a problem with the lenses; looking at the lens from the front, I don't see any difference in the position of the diaphragm when changing the aperture from F36 to f5.6. One of my lens seems to be have a minuscule aperture, the other one a very big one.
Update 1
Okay, I tried again with my 55-300 lens, after a factory reset, and this time I can see through the viewfinder, and if I set the ISO to 12800, I can even take a decent picture of this Rudolph in my LED lighted room.

So, right now only the 18-55 lens appear to be misbehaving. I'll check the diaphragms as @xenoid suggested.

Is the battery fully charged and operational?

Thanks, good point. The battery had 2 out of 3 bars of charge. Initially, it had 1 out of 3; that qualifies as depleted, and when that happens even the shutter button is disabled, and you get a message that nothing is gonna work. But then I charged to 3 bars, and after a while it dropped to 2, but the camera seemed operational beside for the picture being too dark. I have been charging another battery for a few hours, because I do suspect that maybe the first battery could be faulty.

I just installed another, fully charged battery, and it made no difference.

Can you try with a different lens? Or peer in the lens and see if you can see a closed diaphragm? I would expect this kind of behavior if the lens diaphragm isn't fully open.

"Subject too dark" normally means the camera cannot find focus due to the exposure.
It sounds to me like your exposure settings are just inadequate (too dark). It's also possible that you have a negative exposure compensation set somewhat negating auto corrections/settings.
You will not see the aperture change when you change the setting; it only stops down during the time the exposure is made. But it should be at maximum when at rest unless you have a mechanical aperture ring on the lens... technically, even then as it should normally be set to maximum and locked there.

Thanks. I did a factory reset. After that I took all actions that I am aware of that should increase the intake/sensitivity to light (aperture, shutting time, ISO) and it stays black. I can only see light sources, like the lights on my Christmas tree. If I remove the lens, the picture become bright, but of course it's blurry because I believe there is nothing between the CCD and the subject, and all optical rays hit everything from multiple angles.

Unless you are looking at live view (the LCD), changing exposure settings will not change the scene view (through the viewfinder).

There are two possibilities which would cause this behavior: the lenses are not communicating with your Nikon D5300, or the body is not operating the aperture stop-down mechanism. On a DSLR, whether you are looking through the lens via the prism finder or using live-view, you should see the image at the same brightness as the scene appears to your eyes. If the image is darker, then the lens's aperture is stuck in the stopped down position.
In normal circumstances, no matter what f/stop the lens is set, the physical aperture remains completely open until the shutter release is activated. Then the camera causes the lens to close to the correct aperture, the shutter fires, and then the aperture returns to maximum. This is accomplished either mechanically or electronically. Mechanically, the camera operates a lever in the lens which close the aperture to the correct f/stop. Electronically the camera communicates the status of the shutter to the lens which then electro-mechanically closes the aperture. Since this happens while the mirror is locked up, you don't see the brightness change in the viewfinder.
Some DSLRs have a "depth of field preview" mechanism. This stops the aperture down independently of the shutter, so that the user can see the actual depth of field. If the aperture is small, the user will see a much dimmer image when this is activated. Unfortunately the Nikon D5300 does not have this mechanism (other Nikons do).
The best test is to try a different lens. You indicated that both lenses you tried have been damaged in some way. This could also damage the aperture stop-down mechanism, keeping the aperture closed down when the shutter is not activated. If you look through the lens when it is off the camera and you see the aperture blades, this indicates damage to the lens's stop-down mechanism. If your lenses communicate with the camera electronically it is possible to reset the camera/lens software to resolve the issue. If your lenses use a mechanical connection then they need repair. Testing with a lens known to operate properly will rule out camera body malfunction.


Like, if I look at my Christmas tree, I see the lights, but nothing
else. If I point it to the window, I see the street, but nothing from
the room I am in.

In both these cases the brightest light in the frame is overpowering the much dimmer light in the rest of the frame. Your camera (and all of the rest of our camera's, too) can only capture a limited range of brightness at the same time. If you've set the camera to protect the highlights (that is, the brightest part of the scene), then parts of the scene that are much darker will not be bright enough to be anything but very dark. If, on the other hand, you set the camera to expose so that the darker details are captured, the brightest parts of the image will be grossly over exposed.
